# consistent webpack options when there are multiple chained loaders

Tags: javascript, webpack

In webpack, some loaders have options with queries:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test:   /\.css$/,
            loader: `css?minimize&root=${path.resolve('.')}!postcss`
        }
    ]
},
```

and others in their own section, such as [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader)

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test:   /\.css$/,
            loader: "style!css!postcss"
        }
    ]
},
postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
}
```

Is there a way to move all loader options into the main options like postcss instead of using queries to ensure consistency? Ideally the following would work:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test:   /\.css$/,
            loader: "style!css!postcss"
        }
    ]
},
css: {
    minimize: true,
    root: path.resolve('.')
}
postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
}
```

**[edit]** there appear to be some "workarounds" [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/482) from 2014 but no real solution.

Comment: Can we use es6 functionality?

Comment: @JonSurrell Sure although that's a minor issue in this case.

Comment: The most obvious solution is just moving loader-config to an external variable and referencing it from inside the configuration. Is that valid? A good DRY approach.

Comment: @JonSurrell Interesting thought but I don't really see why it's better than one of those workarounds. Or if I'm not understanding correctly, could you post an example?

Comment: It would have to be used in conjunction with another workaround. But if you're using the same loader and want the same config, you don't have to rewrite. I assumed that was the goal of this, otherwise what is the advantage of what you're trying to achieve? (I'll post an answer with this approach)

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this:

```
{
    test: /\.png$/,
    loader: "url-loader",
    query: { mimetype: "image/png" }
}
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
const URL_LOADER_CONFIG = { mimetype: "image/png" }

module.exports = {
  // ...
  {
    test: /\.png$/,
    loader: "url-loader",
    query: URL_LOADER_CONFIG
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how that works with multiple loaders.

As per the [workarounds you mention](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/482) and [docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#configuration) you can also inline JSON:

```
const URL_LOADER_CONFIG = { mimetype: "image/png" }
const OTHER_LOADER_CONFIG = { other: "config" }

const q = (config) => JSON.stringify(q)

module.exports = {
  // ...
  {
    test: /\.png$/,
    loader: `url-loader?${q(URL_LOADER_CONFIG)}!other-loader?${q(OTHER_LOADER_CONFIG)}`
  }
}
```